No mouse pointer in Enduro Racer
I run Hatari emulator on Linux with this cli
 hatari --disk-a /home/user/Enduro\ Racer\ \(1987\)\(Activision\)\[cr\ Axel\ Follet\].zip 

I see the game intro launching "enduro.prg" from a:\ disk
But I cannot start the game. In a Youtube video I see a "big arrow" like Windows 3.1 mouse cursor appear:

and he can select options (start game, etc..).
How can I make this "big arrow" appear?

I'm making a guess, but given the time period it's possible they were copying the popular Amiga UI convention in which case you need to use the right mouse button to reveal the menu.

Hatari is a modern emulator, last release being only a couple of years old, so there is nothing retro about using it. If you have problems using Hatari, contact Hatari manuals, user forums, or developers.

Note that the problem here has nothing to do with Hatari or any other emulator, but with how the (cracked) game is started. As such it isn’t about using Hatari and is therefore not off-topic (at least, not for that reason).

This question does raise the point of where a question like this would go. The question seems like arqade - since it's asking how to work/activate a game's menu, but the answer below is more rcse since it is to do with how the game was launched in the retro computer's filesystem. Does Gaming se accept 'how do I set up/launch game X?' questions, or is it purely how to play them?

@knol with the added subtlety that this is about launching a cracked game using something akin to a trainer. The uncracked game is started by booting from its floppy, not through GEM, and doesn’t have a menu. The cracked floppy being used here helpfully opens a file window set up to show LAUNCHER.PRG on the GEM desktop.

@StephenKitt Agreed. It's a weak question, but not per se off topic. more of the missing research kind. Like asking why hitting Reset restarts a computer :))

Solution found: the game must be launched by "launcher" not from "enduro.prg"
Then using right mouse to make the menu appear and finally start the game
